# Скрипт не работает с файлами при запуске через cron

Tags: php, файлы, cron

Есть скрипт, который работает с БД. Сразу после запуска записывает в файл "Идёт обновление", а перед выходом "Обновлено [дата]". Если запускать через cron, то всё работает, но запись в файл не происходит. Почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите права на файл и владельца файла. Через крон и из под апача разные пользователи скорее всего. Либо измените права на 0777, либо измените владельца файла

Comment: Спасибо! Но это была не единственная проблема - оказывается, если вызывать через cron, то файл создаётся не там, где надо, а в той папке, где и папка public_html

Comment: Используйте функцию chdir для перехода в нужный каталог, чтобы там создавался файл или в корень проекта, чтобы от него создавались пути сохранения файлов